# How do I get the Monkey achievement?

Tags: edge

The "Monkey" achievement has the description

> Unleash the nibbling totem monkey head in "babylonian"

I have completed "babylonian" by two different paths: one where I press the one visible button, and one where I don't and I can get all of the prisms. Neither made the achievement unlock. What do I have to do to the it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to press the tiles at the top of the structure in the right order so they don't play a noise when going over them. The tile at the bottom left of the screen counts as the first one. This involves skipping over a few tiles and entering the colored finish zone. If you make a mistake you can simply go back to the first tile at the bottom left to reset everything.

This is the actual order - N marks north.

```
 ___________________
| 4 |   | N |   |   |
|___|___|___|___|___|
| 2 | o | o | o |   |
|___|___|___|___|___|
| 5 | o | X | o |   |
|___|___|___|___|___|
| 3 | o | o | o |   |
|___|___|___|___|___|
| 1 |   |   |   |   |
|___|___|___|___|___|
```